# How to validate file except image in yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I want to upload a apk file with yii2 framework.

**In Model**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['apkFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'apk','mimeTypes'=>'application/*'],
    ];
}

public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->apkFile->saveAs('affiliate/apkuploads/' . $this->apkFile->baseName . '.' . $this->apkFile->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ManageLinks();
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    if(!empty($post)){
        $model->apkFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'apkFile');

        if ($model->upload()) {
            echo 'True';
        }else{
            echo 'False';
        }
    }
    return;
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'data' => $data,
    ]);

}
```

**In form**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'apkFile')->fileInput() ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

After executing this i get a false return. Please help me with this.
In my localhost i host yii2 framework under affiliate folder. My full url is:

```
http://localhost/affiliate/web/index.php
```

Comment: Please post code for the form as well

Comment: @Unknown I edit the question with my form data please check.

Comment: If validation is falling print out the errors to see why.
`print_r($model->errors)` or include an error summary `$form->errorSummary($model);` on the form.

Answer (score -1):

Pass

```
['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
```

in your form begin i.e

```
<?= Html::beginForm(['order/update', 'id' => $id], 'post', ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
```

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#creating-forms

Comment: By adding `ActiveForm::begin();` it is automatically add enctype attribute in the form.

Comment: var_dump($_FILES); check do you get file in this ? Also print var_dump($model->getErrors()); to check what are the errors while validating.